# Email to Case Premium with Sales Cloud License

Tags: email2case, servicecloud, sales

Can I install and use Email to Case Premium App without having the Service Cloud License. I have a client that only has Sales Cloud and want to use some of the Cases functionality.

Thanks

Sanchit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sales Cloud license provides case management features and `Email-to-Case` functionality is included in this.

Since, `Email to Case Premium App` has been built on top of `Email-to-Case` you should be able to do this.

Hopefully, you will not be managing cases through Service Cloud Console or Entitlement/Milestones/Service Contracts with the Cases. In this scenario, you need to use Service Cloud licenses.

[image: Licenses]